# Chrome Extension and CORS Frstration

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Apparently resolving CORS problems is frustrating for everyone. I'm writing a Chrome extension for mturk and everything I found on resolving CORS has failed. Most of the solutions I found are server side to which I obviously don't have access. From what I've found there are about 1000 ways suggested using "content_security_policy" in my manifest none of which work. Is there someone out there that has knowledge of mturk extensions and how to resolve the CORS problem? TIA.

FWIW, this is the manifest without any CORS resolutions:

**edited manifest**

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,

   "name": "Auto_Select",
   "description": "This extension auto selects Mturk HITs",
   "version": "1.0",

   "action": {
      "default_icon": "auto_select.png",
      "type": "module",
      "default_popup": "auto_select.html"
   },
   "permissions": [
     "activeTab",
   ],
   "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
```

]
}

Comment: Resolving CORS issues is only frustrating for those of use who are expecting to exploit cross site scripting. Please explain more about your CORS issue and show us that the API that you are calling responds correctly to OPTIONs requests and what the accept headers contain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I said in the OP this is an extension for mturk (Amazon Mechanical Turk). I have not used any OPTIONs requests as that was not in any of the suggested solutions I found. I'll have to look into that and get back to you. The script is supposed to access an mturk URL (worker.mturk.com/projects.json) and manipulate the returned data.

Comment: OPTIONs will only validate the behaviour of the services you are interacting with. One of the problems with CORS related issues is that in some cases the issue is not CORS related at all! I am unfamiliar with `mturk` though, I think this post needs some more information to attract more knowledgable members.

Comment: To make external requests you need to add that host or `"<all_urls>"` to `host_permissions` in manifest.json. Don't forget to reload the extension afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. That suggestion was no where I found after hours of searching. That eliminated the error (I think) but the fetch of the URL returned nothing nor did I get an error. I need to look at the javascript now.